# How to get the portion of image inside rectangle for cropping , windows phone 8

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an image, and a rectangle on top of it.The image can be zoomed and dragged .I need to get the portion of the image inside the rectangle after these operations and save it as a jpeg.

This is my code,

```
private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
{
    initialAngle = compositeTransform.Rotation;
    initialScale = compositeTransform.ScaleX;
}

private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (1.0 <= (initialScale * e.DistanceRatio))
    {
        compositeTransform.ScaleX = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
        compositeTransform.ScaleY = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
    }
}

  private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
{
compositeTransform.TranslateX += e.HorizontalChange;
compositeTransform.TranslateY += e.VerticalChange;
 }
```

and my XAML is

```
<Image x:Name="mypic" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="79,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="345" >
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" />
                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="transform" />
                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="compositeTransform"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="OnDragDelta" PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            </Image>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="111,26,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233" Opacity="0.1" StrokeThickness="3"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,396,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="ClipImage"/>
```

In the ClipImage method how do I get the cropped image? Im not using canvas here.. Is using  canvas mandatory for this?In case Im moving the rectangle i can call CompositionTarget.Rendering to get the current x,y points .How do I proceed in this scenario?

EDIT:
Im now able to get portion of image inside rectangle with the following code..

```
  void ClipImage()
{
    RectangleGeometry geo = new RectangleGeometry();
    r = (Rectangle)rect;
    GeneralTransform gt = r.TransformToVisual(LayoutRoot);
    Point p = gt.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    geo.Rect = new Rect(p.X, p.Y, (r.Width) + 50, (r.Height) + 50);
    mypic.Clip = geo;
    r.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

    TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform();
    t.X = -p.X;
    t.Y = -p.Y;
    mypic.RenderTransform = t;

}
```

This works fine when I don't pan or zoom the image, but when the image is zoomed by user, this doesnt work.Can some one pls help..

Comment: I'd use Nokia Imaging SDK for this.

Comment: @Creator I did go through the documentation and sample,I found ways to draw rectangle on the image to crop,I dint find anything pertaining to my scenario.May be I should delve deeper..

Comment: I was just providing the alternative, since I've used Nokia Imaging SDK only for all kind of image manipulation. It's easier with that.